# Cannot open Google Chromium on my windows from Ubuntu on Mobaxterm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, putty, x11-forwarding

I have Ubuntu server where Google Chrome is installed. I am able to access that server using SSH from my Windows machine via Mobaxterm. I need to open Google Chromium on my machine which will open Ubuntu web page from Apache like http://localhost:8080 on my windows Chromium. Getting below error:

> ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: cannot open display:

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the same, i will make sure this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command before opening chromium browser on your mobaxterm

> **export DISPLAY=your_ipaddress:0.0**

For Ex:-
Let us consider ip address as 192.168.0.1, then your command should be:

> **export DISPLAY=192.168.0.1:0.0**

Comment: Should the IP be the WSL ipv4 address or the local area connection ipv4 address?